# NoSuchObjectException in Pig to HIve Hacatalog

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

```
data = load 'tablename'using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
//Did some etl;
Store finalresult into 'tablename'   USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

I able to load data from hive pig through org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); but not able to store.

Gives Exception:

> ERROR 1115: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2001 :
>   Error setting output information. Cause : NoSuchObjectException

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you made a typo mistake, but in the command I can see a syntax issue near **'into to'** ,

please try:

```
Store finalresult into  'tablename'   USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Comment: typo while posting question..sorry.I have cross checked many times